# Wordpress 3.5 - error compared with widgets

Tags: wordpress

when WordPress was updated to v3.5 I've got errors in Admin Panel: http://gyazo.com/5ff2e63261a11331dd1df7cdd121d606. Everything works good but widgets don't work (I can't push widget to sidebar).

I know that it's because of my theme, but I can't change them to another, so I have to fix this bug.

Where can be a problem? I'm sure it's something compared with framework of my theme, but I don't know where can I find something useful.

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like some JS error. Try uninstalling unnecessary plugins first.

Comment: There are no plugins. It appears also when I install my template on the completely new website. I know that it's something with framework, because when I changed them to a new, it worked good. The template has newer version, but I can't install them, because in the current version I've made to much modifications that will be removed after update.

Comment: Thats why its better not to touch the main template, plugin or core files.

Comment: Try to create a child template based on the theme framework, then you can update the template as well.

Answer (score 4):

This morning I updated to WP 3.5. After doing so, none of my widgets would expand, couldn't move widgets to and from the sidebar, etc. Same problem you had.

But I found the solution (for me anyway):

Bulletproof Security puts an .htaccess in the wp-admin folder that will prevent widgets from working correctly in 3.5.

[Where I found that info](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/troubleshooting-wordpress-35-master-list?replies=4)

If you have (or have ever) used Bulletproof Security, delete the .htaccess file in your wp-admin folder and all will be well. (At least it worked for me.)

Comment: It appears there is the same conflict with the simple slideshow plugin too.

Answer (score 0):

I've also had the same issue on [AndroidsChick.com](http://www.androidschick.com)

It was driving me crazy....I've done the step by step deactivating plugins and testing.... and on my installation it was the

Widget Logic Visual plug in! Once deactivated everything was back to normal! :)

Now I have to find a replacement for the Widget Logic plug in since all my Widgets are visible!

Hope this helps someone in solving this horrible issue.... :)